# Pass int by reference from C++/CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

It seems like there must be a duplicate question, but I haven't been able to find it.

I'm writing a bridge to let an old C program access some C# objects. The bridge is written in C++/CLI.

In one case there is a C# function that's defined as:

```
public static string GetNameAndValue(out int value);
```

My C++/CLI wrapper function:

```
char* GetNameAndValue(int* value);
```

Which is easy enough to call from C. But how do I call the C# method from C++/CLI?

I first tried the obvious:

```
String ^ str;
str = TheObject::GetNameAndValue(value);
```

That gives me error C2664: Cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'int %'.

Okay, then, how about `GetNameAndValue(%value)`? That gives me error C3071: operator '%' can only be applied to an instance of a ref class or a value-type.

Fair enough. So if I create an `int` I can pass it with `%`??

```
int foo;
str = TheObject::GetNameAndValue(%ix);
```

No dice.  C3071 again. Which I find odd because `int` definitely *is* a value-type. Or is it?

There must be some magic combination of %, ^, &, or some other obscenity that will do what I want, but after swearing at this thing for 30 minutes I'm stumped. And searching Google for different combinations of C++/CLI and C# mostly gives information about how to call C++ from C#.

SO, my question: How do you pass an `int` from C++/CLI to a C# method that expects an `out int` (or `ref int`, if I have to)?

Comment: You've got things badly backwards.  C++/CLI is pretty useless to allow a C program to call a C# method.  It is a language extension that was made to go the other way, from managed code to native code.  Running managed code from a native program requires much bigger weapons, it has to load and initialize the CLR first.  That's going to take more than 30 minutes to sort out.

Comment: @HansPassant: That's not been my experience in the short time I've been working with this. My C program calls a DLL that was compiled with C++/CLI, which in turn calls C# code in another assembly. Works quite well. As I understand it, the C++/CLI DLL loads the runtime. Whatever the case, I've been able to get information from the C# code back to the C code.

Comment: C++/CLI supports __declspec(dllexport), that's the only scenario I can think of where you could have good luck with it.  Same idea as Giesecke's [DllExport] hack.  As posted, your question makes very little sense to me and the problems you are having are entirely normal.  Good luck with it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C#:

```
class MyClass 
{ 
    public static string GetNameAndValue(out int value);
}
```

C++/CLI:

```
int value;
String^ x = MyClass::GetNameAndValue(value);
```

C++/CLI wrapper:

```
CString GetNameAndValue(int* value)
{
    String^ x = MyClass::GetNameAndValue(*value);
    return CString(x);
}
```

C++/CLI wrapper 2:

```
CString GetNameAndValue(int& value)
{
    String^ x = MyClass::GetNameAndValue(value);
    return CString(x);
}
```

It's the same for C# "ref".

Comment: That is *totally* non obvious! So when I do `MyClass::GetNameAndValue(*value)`, the compiler is automatically marshaling it as something like `[out] System::Int32`? It'll take me a bit to test this, but if it works I'll accept the answer.

Comment: It's just like calling C++: "void x(int&);" by passing variable "int v;". Mechanism is the same. There is no cast. For compiler the desired prototype is the same as defined one.

Comment: What's more the only difference between ref and out is that out force you to assign the variable inside method. Otherwise you can think of ref as C++ &. By the way I use C++, C++/CLI, C# for a while and there is really no need to use % symbol, you can define it's equivalent in C# or C++. So in C++/CLI the only additional reference type symbol left to care about is ^.

Comment: There is no way to define anything like a tracking reference in C++. `%` in C++/CLI is unique in that it follows objects around when they move during a heap compaction. Objects moving around during their lifetime is a unique feature of .NET. It doesn't exist in C++, hence there is no facility for a matching reference.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is answered already but only to clarify what the compiler was suggesting with "C2664: Cannot convert parameter 2 from 'int *' to 'int %'".
I think it wanted this(C++/CLI):

```cpp
int a=5
int% foo=a;
str = TheObject::GetNameAndValue(foo);
```

Comment: Not really.  It's a reference parameter, and can bind to an lvalue.  You don't need to create another reference in the caller... and the parameter **won't** bind to the caller's reference anyway.

Comment: The whole point & purpose of my post was to be explicit and clear, without fancy terms. You are of course correct, but very academic. I am of the opinion that simple even over-trivial examples are better. This is actually the problem with MSDN : it is written in a very academic way, so it is counter-intuitive and difficult to grasp in a short time. That is why we have sites like this one.